# How do I position text in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am wondering what do I have to write to position text so it will not only border left side but also right side.

[image]

```
Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Text(
              'TEXTTEXT',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: drbarva,
                fontSize: 15,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  `textAlign: TextAlign.justify`

```
Text(
              "this working for me this is working for me",
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
```